# Masking and Instance Normalization in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, normalization

Assume I have a PyTorch tensor, arranged as shape [N, C, L] where N is the batch size, C is the number of channels or features, and L is the length.  In this case, if one wishes to perform instance normalization, one does something like:

```
N = 20
C = 100
L = 40
m = nn.InstanceNorm1d(C, affine=True)
input = torch.randn(N, C, L)
output = m(input)
```

This will perform a normalization in the L-wise dimension for each N*C = 2000 slices of data, subtracting 2000 means, scaling by 2000 standard deviations, and re-scaling by 100 learnable weight and bias parameters (one per channel).  The unspoken assumption here is that all of these values exist and are meaningful.

But I have a situation where, for the slice N=1, I would like to exclude all data after (say) L=35.  For the slice N=2 (say) all the data are valid.  For the slice N=3, exclude all data after L=30, etc.  This mimics data which are one dimensional time sequences, having multiple features, but which are not the same length.

**How can I perform an instance norm on such data, get correct statistics, and maintain differentiability/AutoGrad information in PyTorch?**

**Update:  While maintaining GPU performance, or at least not killing it dead.**

I cannot...

1. ...Mask with zero values, as this destroys the computer means and variances giving erroneous results
2. ...Mask with np.nan or np.inf, as PyTorch tensors do not ignore such values, but treat them as errors.  They are sticky, and lead to garbage results.  PyTorch currently lacks the equivalent of np.nanmean and np.nanvar.
3. ...Permute or transpose to an amenable arrangement of data; no such approach gives me what I need
4. ...Use a pack_padded_sequence; instance normalization does not operate on that data structure, and one cannot import data into that structure as far as I know.  Also, data re-arrangement would still be necessary, see 3 above.

Am I missing an approach which would give me what I need?  Or perhaps am I missing a method of data re-arrangement which would allow 3 or 4 above to work?

This is an issue faced by recurrent neural networks all the time, hence the pack_padded_sequence functionality, but it isn't quite applicable here.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that if you specify e.g. exclude the last 35 entries, you dont' want the `InstanceNorm`s last 35 weights(and biases) to be updated?

Comment: How do you treat these last 35 values in other modules? (Like `Conv1d` or `Linear` or so?)

Comment: @flawr It's not that I don't want them updated (although technically they shouldn't be.)  It's that normalization relies on the computation of mean and variance, and I want that computation to ignore the masked values.  E.g., [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ___, ___, ___, ___, ___] should be normalized on the basis of a mean of 3 and a population variance of 2, regardless of the masked values denoted by ___ .

Comment: @flawr after computation, they will be masked from the loss function.  Remasking to zero if necessary is an option as well.

Comment: Sot huis means for every batch you pass through your modified `InstanceNorm` you also pass a list/tensor of indices (of size `NxC`) that define what values are relevant, and which one should be masked, right?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is directly possible to implement using the existing `InstanceNorm1d`, the easiest way would probably be implementing it yourself from scratch. I did a quick implementation that should work. To make it a little bit more general this module requires a boolean mask (a boolean tensor of the same size as the input) that specifies which elements should be considered when passing through the instance norm.

```
import torch


class MaskedInstanceNorm1d(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_features, eps=1e-6, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_features = num_features
        self.eps = eps
        self.momentum = momentum
        self.affine = affine
        self.track_running_stats = track_running_stats
        self.gamma = None
        self.beta = None
        if self.affine:
            self.gamma = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones((1, self.num_features, 1), requires_grad=True))
            self.beta = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros((1, self.num_features, 1), requires_grad=True))

        self.running_mean = None
        self.running_variance = None
        if self.affine:
            self.running_mean = torch.zeros((1, self.num_features, 1), requires_grad=True)
            self.running_variance = torch.zeros((1, self.num_features, 1), requires_grad=True)

    def forward(self, x, mask):
        mean = torch.zeros((1, self.num_features, 1), requires_grad=False)
        variance = torch.ones((1, self.num_features, 1), requires_grad=False)

        # compute masked mean and variance of batch
        for c in range(self.num_features):
            if mask[:, c, :].any():
                mean[0, c, 0] = x[:, c, :][mask[:, c, :]].mean()
                variance[0, c, 0] = (x[:, c, :][mask[:, c, :]] - mean[0, c, 0]).pow(2).mean()

        # update running mean and variance
        if self.training and self.track_running_stats:
            for c in range(self.num_features):
                if mask[:, c, :].any():
                    self.running_mean[0, c, 0] = (1-self.momentum) * self.running_mean[0, c, 0] \
                                                 + self.momentum * mean[0, c, 0]
                    self.running_variance[0, c, 0] = (1-self.momentum) * self.running_variance[0, c, 0] \
                                                     + self.momentum * variance[0, c, 0]

        # compute output
        x = (x - mean)/(self.eps + variance).sqrt()

        if self.affine:
            x = x * self.gamma + self.beta

        return x
```

Comment: I am coming to the same conclusion, that it can't be done without implementing or re-implementing something.  I suspect adding nanmean and nanvar to torch, and methodically extending those into the normalization routine, is the cleanest way to go, but that's beyond my time investment horizon.

Comment: Also, the semantics (the loop indices, in particular) of this aren't quite right, but they're easily patched to provide the correct behavior.  I'll have ponder and benchmark this, while hoping someone else sees something I've missed.

Comment: @Novak What exactly is wong? I tested it and it works a just like we discussed, only the masked entries are considered in the updates, and the unmasked basically pass through an identity.

Comment: The direction of the statistics are wrong, and the grouping isn't quite right; a naive interpretation needs nested loops in some locations.  Make a random tensor of shape [3, 2, 4], and test it against the default implementation of InstanceNorm1d().  If the mask tensor is set to all True you should see identical results, but you won't.

Comment: Also-- and this is what I was really afraid of-- performance on GPU device goes down the drain because of those loops.

Comment: Ah I see, we should also compute the stats for each batch entry, but that can easily be adjusted. If you want better performance you can try to vectorize this approach, after all it is just a quick sketch and not production level code.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I'm doing now.  If I get something I like, I will post it as an answer but probably not accept it.